# About uk visa refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My visa application to visit my father in the UK has been refused because I said that I will stay in the UK for 60 days while I'm a student in my country.  They said that I didn't provide any document that explains why I'm going to be absent for 2 months while I'm a student, plus I didn't provide any documents that shows that I can support my self financially here.

Should I wait to reapply and can I change the period of 2 months in a new application?

Comment: I had a similar refusal many many years ago, asking to spend more time than reasonable _on the surface_. **If possible consider postponing your trip to the next vacation**. Changing your mind in a short period of time is not viewed favorably by Entry Clearance Officers. They will feel you are telling them anything you think they want to hear. A second successive refusal in a short period of time is not a good thing. Additionally I suggest you read as much about UK visa questions here as you can particularly those by [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow)

Comment: U mean the next 15 days vacation?

Comment: Personally I would wait a year but note, this is just a suggestion. If you are student then realistically you can only apply twice in a year during school vacations, during your school breaks. People have been approved when they applied a week later or even a day later, it depends on what the refusal was about. Your case involves a **change of plan or duration**. According to ECO thinking, reliable/stable people don't just change their mind.

Comment: What is your fathers immigration status in the UK? It can be a big factor. Preferably post a picture of your refusal notice with personal details blacked out.

Comment: He's a british citizen.
Do u mean that even if i waited a long time changing the periode will be a problem?

Comment: @Dabbaish Wail The most important thing is to make sure that your travel plan is credible in the context of your life in your home country. For example, the ECO would probably not find it credible that a student would take time out for a visit during term time or immediately before finals, or that someone planned to spend many times their monthly income on a single trip, or that someone with whom they have no obvious link is sponsoring their trip.

Answer (score 4):

There is no requirement to wait before reapplying, nor does a refusal mean that you cannot vary the intended length of your visit in a new application. However, you must make certain you address all the refusal reasons in your new application, including evidence shortfalls. You will also have to disclose the refusal in all subsequent applications for a U.K. visa.